# HTML/CSS Circle around a string's size not changing

Tags: html, css, sass

When I try to change height/width of circle border, it doesn't do anything. I've tried separating spans. Also, sorry that I can't post the images, I don't have enough karma as I lost my old account so I had to add the links to Imgur.

HTML:

```
this.mNavBarElements = [
            {
                id: 'hide_icon_container',
                position: 'left',
                interior: HTMLGenerator_getImage({id: 'hide_icon', src: Resources.resources.ARROWLEFTDARKGREY.src})
            },
            {position: 'center', interior: HTMLGenerator_getSpan({style: 'navbar_title calculate_width', interior: 'Notifications'})},
            {position: 'right', style: 'navbar_title calculate_width', id: 'unread_notifications_button', interior: HTMLGenerator_getSpan({id: 'number_of_unread_circle', interior: '<span id="number_of_unread_text">5</span>'}) +
            HTMLGenerator_getSpan({interior: 'Unread'})}
```

Which translates to:
[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvZn0.png)

CSS:

```
.NotificationSubscriptions_panel {

    #nav_bar {

        .navbar_title {
            color: #2B2B2A;
        }

            #unread_notifications_button {
                line-height: 18px;
                color: #A27476;
                font-size: 13px;
            

                #number_of_unread_circle {
                  
                }

                #number_of_unread_text {
                    position: relative;
                    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
                    height: 15px; width: 15px; 
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    top: 50%;
                    text-align: center;
                    line-height: 0px;
                }
        }
    }




    .switch_option_container {
        justify-content: space-around !important;

        .switch_option_container:first-of-type{
            background-color: #FCFCFC;
        }

        .switch_row_right{
            padding-right: 22px;
        }
    }
    .scroll_container {
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
        padding-top: 88px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

What I have:
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1QaM.png)

What I want:
[Need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVRbh.png)

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: A <span> element can't be effectively sized unless you change its display property to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: I didn't know that @kshetline, thanks for the advice! I think I got it all sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kshetline for the simple solution!
All I needed to do was add `display: inline-block` to my CSS and with a little bit of styling, that completely fixed my problem. I had no idea that span's required inline-block to be adjusted in size.